# mysql Query optimization task

Tags: mysql

Mentioned below is the query and the tables its is being run on ...

```
SELECT * FROM 
tfl_acquistions a, 
tfl_property_attributes b WHERE 
a.id = b.property_id AND 
attribute_id ='111' AND 
a.id ='53a8288c03a6823';
```

Table tfl_acquistions

```
CREATE TABLE `tfl_acquistions` ( 
`id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`address` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`city` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`state` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`zip` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`county` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`country` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`status` ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y', 
`customer_case` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`circle_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`visneta_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`add_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00', 
`apt_no` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`profile_picture` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
INDEX `address` (`address`), 
INDEX `city` (`city`), 
INDEX `state` (`state`), 
INDEX `zip` (`zip`), 
INDEX `status` (`status`), 
INDEX `customer_case` (`customer_case`), 
INDEX `circle_id` (`circle_id`), 
INDEX `visneta_id` (`visneta_id`) 
)
```

Table tfl_property_attributes

```
CREATE TABLE `tfl_property_attributes` ( 
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`property_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
`attribute_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`value` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`update_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`update_by` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
INDEX `attribute_id` (`attribute_id`), 
INDEX `property_id` (`property_id`), 
INDEX `property_id_2` (`property_id`, `attribute_id`) 
)
```

I am on a task to optimized this query and i am new  .... any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you checked the query plan? What is that you want to optimize? Is it running slow? What is the time it's taking now and what are you thinking it should be post optimization?

Comment: its slow because of numerous records in tfl_acquistions.

Comment: that's still ok but why you want to optimize?

Comment: because the page loads for a long time for fetching and displaying records

Comment: i think optimizer should take care of it. TBH i dont see issue with query itself. But may be from where you are calling and processing it like creating connection etc.

Comment: @almasshaikh There is an issue with this query. It is that it can not use any indexes, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM 
tfl_acquistions a JOIN
tfl_property_attributes b ON a.id = b.property_id WHERE
b.property_id = '53a8288c03a6823' AND b.attribute_id = '111';
```

This way MySQL will be able to use the index `property_id_2` (`property_id`, `attribute_id`) you have created on the second table. Currently, it can't use any indexes.

Try putting `EXPLAIN` keyword in front of queries to see how MySQL plans to perform them, you'll see that your previous query does not use any index.